# how can someone use the smart contract deployed on Rinkeby network? what are next steps after successful deployment?

Tags: truffle, infura, rinkeby, npm

I am new to the smart contract and blockchain technology but learning step by step. I developed a small bidding smart contract in solidity. Using Truffle, NPM and Infura, I deployed it in the Rinkeby test network. Deployment is successful. Now I want to test the functionality and want to others to access it so that they can test it too. It is a bidding contract. I want to know if the actual functionality has been incorporated in it. I could not find a way to use the contract on Rinkeby network. Where should the transactions happen to do the bidding? How to direct the transactions to Auction contract? How can I actually involve people to do the bidding? I haven't posted the code as it has no issue. Any inputs would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not exactly but I believe it would be answered soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way a mainnet contract gets used - same options.

You can use `truffle console` which might be sufficient because you seem to be set up to connect to Rinkeby. You'll get a JavaScript interface with Web3 loaded.

You can build a HTML interface and, after loading dependencies, get the MetaMask plug-in going. It gives the user a way to select the network to use.

You can head over to https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/ and "verify" the contract which is about copy/paste the source code at the address you deployed to and they will confirm the bytecode matches. That will also give them knowledge of the ABI and open up their tabs to read/write from/to the contract.

For early development, many developers work with Remix in the early stages because it gives you quick feedback about compiler errors and a convenient interface for superficial function testing. At later stages, a private (1 node) network can simulate things without the fuss of deployment and that can help you dev/test a UI, so when the time comes to actually release on a testnet, your mode of interacting will be a well-defined trail - probably a user interface that presents the functions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What does it mean by truffle<rinkeby> when I give truffle console in the cli?

Comment: It means you are in the JavaScript cli for truffle and it is talking to rinkeby. Progress.

Comment: You can go `> version` or `var x = 10;` or go nuts and go `var instance; MyContract.deployed().then(function(res) { instance = res; });` You should get an instance of your contract. Go `> instance` call a function. Asynchronous approach I used is a promise. Use promises for most things.